# eclipse, subversive subclipse and colons

Tags: eclipse, special-characters, subclipse, subversive

I am using subclipse with eclipse and yesterday I checked in some files where the file name included colons ":". Sublicpse handled it well without any problems but now I cannot check out the project on my colleagues computer. He uses subversive rather than subclipse.

Does anybody know whether special characters such as colons cause problems when using subversive?

Cheers
tom